# How to get canvas from tileLayer Leaflet 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, leaflet

I'm using the [Leaflet.VectorGrid plugin](https://github.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.VectorGrid) to draw tiles sliced via geojson-vt in Leaflet 1.0.

I want to add a gradient to paths while drawing. I found [code](http://jsfiddle.net/51toapv2/) on stackoverflow for adding gradient along a path but it needs a canvas.

My question is: how to get a reference to the canvas, or its context (`ctx`) to draw on it?

Here is my code to add a tileLayer:

```
var tileLayer = L.vectorGrid.slicer(data, {
        rendererFactory: L.canvas.tilee,
        vectorTileLayerStyles: {
            sliced: function(properties, zoom) {                    
                var endColor=70;       

                // var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(begin[0], begin[1], end[0], end[1]);
                // grad.addColorStop(0, begin[2]);
                // grad.addColorStop(1, end[2]);
                // ctx.strokeStyle = grad;

                return {                        
                    stroke: true,
                    fill: true,
                    color: endColor < 20? 'red' :
                            endColor < 50? 'orange' :
                            endColor < 70? 'yellow' :
                            endColor < 100? 'green' : 'blue',/
                    weight: 5,
                }
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the creator of Leaflet.VectorGrid.

> My question is: how to get a reference to the canvas, or its context (ctx) to draw on it?

The answer is: you **don't**. The Leaflet code is structured in a way that abstracts the canvas context away. The goal of this design is to let the user focus on the geometries and not on the rendering, and provide cross-compatibility thanks to dual SVG support. SVG-only or canvas-only features are discouraged.

Furthermore, canvases in Leaflet.VectorGrid inherit from `L.Canvas`. Note that vanilla `L.Canvas` does *not* have support for gradients along lines, so you should focus on [using a plugin that allows for gradients on polylines](https://github.com/iosphere/Leaflet.hotline), and only then worry about how to make that work with vector tiles.

That will involve understanding how both plugins monkey-patch the Leaflet classes, in which order, and how the class inheritances are handled.

And once you have understand that, you will have to worry about instantiating `L.Hotline`s from within the `L.GeoJSON`s that are instantiated within the sliced tiles.

TL;DR: Read and understand the code for Leaflet.VectorGrid and Leaflet.Hotline.

Comment: Thanks for your, answer. It gave me a new way of thinking about my problem.

Comment: I took your advice in making my application. I used Your's Leaflet.VectorGrid, and some code from Hotline.js.
But now i have another problem. 
I want to redraw my VectorGrid layer.
At the beginning i tried to use simple redraw() function on VectorGrid but the problem is that my tiles are removing all, and then drawing all. And there is a huge delay between this two functions so for a 2 seconds I have an "empty" map. I want to eliminate this bug. 
For example when i zooming the VectorGrid is redrawing without any "empty" moment. Could You help me with that?

Comment: Now i added to VectorGrid.js _update method, and delete this fragment where is setting tile.current to true or push to queue to draw. But i don't know it is a good way to do this